# How to get a nullable datetime value and cast it to a string using razor?

Tags: c#, razor

I am trying to format a model property that is a nullable datetime.
Currently the razor output is not recognizing the below syntax:

```
 @Model.UpdatedDate?.ToString("dddd MMMM dd, yyyy")
```

It is only rendering the @Model.UpdatedDate part, everything after the ? is just a plain string in the html output.

I tried to wrap it in {} but that is for inline code with no output.

What is the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in parens to be explicit  about the expression:

```
@(Model.UpdatedDate?.ToString("dddd MMMM dd, yyyy"))
```